# Excel Range.Find becoming slower and slower

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have a file with column like this:

- K
- K
- K
- SND
- P
- P
- SND
- K

...

The length of the column is for example 20000. I use the following C# code to move along this column:

```
        while (true)
        {
            // Find SND
            dest_cells = ex_cells.Find("SND", dest_cells, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns,
                                   Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, false, false);

            // END?
            if (dest_cells.Row < row)
                return false;

            row = dest_cells.Row;


            // Find K
            dest_cells = ex_cells.Find("K", dest_cells, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns,
                                   Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, false, false);

            // END?
            if (dest_cells.Row < row)
                return false;

            row = dest_cells.Row;

            // Some operations
            /*there were some operations, but I commented them. So they don't influence on performance*/
        }
```

The duration of each consequtive search is increasing. I didn't measure time. But only for explanation let it be: first Find takes 0.1 s, second 0.2 s, tenth 1 s, twenties 2 s and so on.

Why? I can't understand

Comment: because you are searching further and further through the range each time?

Comment: Yes.... but whether I do something wrong?

Comment: that all depends what you want to achieve, if the code works and you have no limitation on performance it may be sub optimal but right.

Comment: performance is very important. This function works ages. Could you say me optimal solution please?

Comment: And my task is to get information from the cell in other column. The row of this cell is the row of first "K" in each subgroup of "K"s

Comment: Each subgroup of "K"s is separated by at least one SND

Comment: Could you just not be clearing one of the range variables so the size is growing each time?

Comment: Sorry... what do you mean? I always search in range "ex_cells". It is something like A1:A20000. And I don't change it's size. Actually I tried to decrease it's size (after each search upper part was thrown) but it didn't chang anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way depends on what operations you want to do: but probably the best way is to assign the column(s) of data to an object array and process that (there is a very high overhead for each interop call to the Excel object model). For a comparison of various approaches see http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and article. I think it's the best way for me. But I still don't understand why first seach lasts miliseconds and hundredth search lasts several seconds. I tried to do the same operations manually and record macro. I didn't encounter this problem in this case and code of macros is almost the same

Answer (score 0):

when you are looping you are using `dest_cells` as the start point to find the next match. But this variable is shared between finding `K` and finding `SND` and the more the distribution of these are seperated (after matches are found) then the more the code will need to cycle through increased areas. Use different variables such as `matchK` and `matchSnd`

Comment: Do you mean? 
            matchK = ex_cells.Find("SND", matchSnd, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, false, false);
            matchSnd = ex_cells.Find("SND", matchK, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, false, false);

Comment: try `matchK = ex_cells.Find("SND", matchK... matchSnd = ex_cells.Find("SND", matchSnd...`. Read up on the [Find Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find(office.11).aspx), especially the `After` parameter

Comment: But in your code you are looking only for "SND". And if you meant 'matchK = ex_cells.Find("K", matchK... matchSnd = ex_cells.Find("SND", matchSnd...' than I'll find every "K" in subgroup (not only first)